# Swift optional inout parameters and nil

Tags: swift, option-type

Is it possible to have an `Optional` `inout` parameter to a function in Swift? I am trying to do this:

```
func testFunc( inout optionalParam: MyClass? ) {
    if optionalParam {
        ...
    }
}
```

...but when I try to call it and pass `nil`, it is giving me a strange compile error:

```
Type 'inout MyClass?' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'
```

I don't see why my class should have to conform to some special protocol when it's already declared as an optional.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It won't compile because the function expecting a reference but you passed `nil`. The problem have nothing to do with optional.

By declaring parameter with `inout` means that you will assign some value to it inside the function body. How can it assign value to `nil`?

You need to call it like

```
var a : MyClass? = nil
testFunc(&a) // value of a can be changed inside the function
```

---

If you know C++, this is C++ version of your code without optional

```
struct MyClass {};    
void testFunc(MyClass &p) {}
int main () { testFunc(nullptr); }
```

and you have this error message

```
main.cpp:6:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'nullptr_t' to 'MyClass &' for 1st argument
```

which is kind of equivalent to the on you got (but easier to understand)

Comment: So I guess the answer is *no* then. I'm sure this was possible in Objective-C. Oh well.

Comment: @chaiguy maybe you can try pointer like `AutoreleasingPointer<MyClass>`. but it is ugly IMO.

Comment: @devios it definitely was possible in Objective-C

Comment: this is why nils are toxic

Comment: The Swift example is fine and makes it possible.

Answer (score 5):

Actually what @devios1 needs is "optional pointer". 
But inout MyClass? means "pointer to an optional".
The following should work in Swift 4

```
class MyClass {
    // func foo() {}
}

func testFunc(_ optionalParam: UnsafeMutablePointer<MyClass>? ) {
    if let optionalParam = optionalParam {
        // optionalParam.pointee.foo()
        // optionalParam.pointee = MyClass()
    }
}

testFunc(nil)

var myClass = MyClass()
testFunc(&myClass)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, and it may have everything to do with [Closure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=bTDg-SqKgeQ).()

The optional can have a nil value, but it is not expecting nil. So the optional would work if you simply did not pass it to the function or passed a variable of type MyClass? with value nil. Like Bryan states.

When you write the function it has to have a default value to be an optional param like so:

```
func testFunc(inout optionalParam:MyClass?={var nilRef:MyClass?;return &nilRef}()) {
    if optionalParam != nil {
        ...
    }
}
```

Notice `if optionalParam {...}` is changed to `if optionalParam != nil {...}`

you can NOT uwwrap `optionalParam` without checking it,i.e.`if optionalParam? != nil`, as uwrapping, `optionalParam?` fails when `optionalParam==nil`. ~note, `var a :MyClass?` has a value of nil until it is assigned.

Call is either, `testFunc(optionalParam:&a)` or `testFunc()`, but never `testFunc(nil)`

Think you may be getting two separate concepts intertwined as they have similar names, optional parameters and optionals. Optionals are variables with an extended nil condition. Optional parameters are function parameters which are optional.

Further reading [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_243). Apple is trying to change the verbiage from optional parameter to 'parameters with default values'. It is unfortunate they didn't incorporate optional parameter behavior within these new optional thingies.  What is the point of passing nil optionals as optionals if they will fail when unwrapped. Maybe it gets deeper at the heart of what this optional thing is if it can be passed before unwrapping... Schrodinger's cat

Comment: I forgot to mention the common catch PHRASE in a try BLOCK would be `if a == nil {a = MyClass();}`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to compile in Swift 3.0 for me on Xcode: I get the error `'&' can only appear immediately in a call argument list`

Answer (score 1):

The exact [passage from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158) is:

> You can only pass a variable as the argument for an in-out parameter.
>   You cannot pass a constant or a literal value as the argument, because
>   constants and literals cannot be modified. You place an ampersand (&)
>   directly before a variable’s name when you pass it as an argument to
>   an inout parameter, to indicate that it can be modified by the
>   function.

Note however, that (edited) per @gnasher's comment, you only need to pass a class as inout (aka by reference), if you intend or want to allow for the instance to be / being replaced by another instance, and not just have the original modified.  The passage in the documentation that covers this is:

> In-Out Parameters
>
> Variable parameters, as described above, can only be changed within
>   the function itself. If you want a function to modify a parameter’s
>   value, and you want those changes to persist after the function call
>   has ended, define that parameter as an in-out parameter instead.

Here are three tests that cover the usage of var and inout.

```
class Bar : Printable {
    var value = 1

    init(_ value:Int) { self.value = value }
    var description:String { return "Bar is: \(value)" }
}

let bar = Bar(1)
func changeBarWithoutInoutSinceBarIsAClassYaySwift(b:Bar) { b.value = 2 }
changeBarWithoutInoutSinceBarIsAClassYaySwift(bar)
println("after: \(bar)") // 2

var bar2 = Bar(0)
func tryToReplaceLocalBarWithoutInout(var b:Bar) { b = Bar(99) }
tryToReplaceLocalBarWithoutInout(bar2)
println("after: \(bar2)") // 0

var bar3 = Bar(0)
func replaceClassInstanceViaInout(inout b:Bar) { b = Bar(99) }
replaceClassInstanceViaInout(&bar3)
println("after: \(bar3)") // 99
```

Comment: Actually, inout works just the same with references (classes). Except the value of a struct is all the elements of the struct, while the value of a reference is just the reference itself. If you pass NSMutableString thisString you can't change it to NSMutableString thatString, unless you use var or inout. Changing the characters doesn't change the reference.

Comment: @gnasher, thanks for posting that, that makes more sense.  I updated my answer accordingly.