# Need help in using Swift inout with optional

Tags: swift

This is the function I tried to use

```
func merge(inout A: DNode?, inout And B: DNode?) -> DNode? {
    if A == nil && B == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if A == nil {
        return B
    }
    if B == nil {
        return A
    }
    return A!.isLessThan(B!) ? A! : B!
}
```

Here is how I tried to use the function 'merge'

```
class Heap {
    var minDNode: DNode?

    func start(inout newNode: DNode) {
        self.minDNode = merge(&self.minDNode, And: &newNode) // error
        // Cannot invoke 'merge' with an argument list of type '(inout DNode?, And: inout DNode)'
    }

    func merge(inout A: DNode?, inout And B: DNode?) -> DNode? {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I fix the problem?

Looking at the answer from [Swift optional inout parameters and nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690710/swift-optional-inout-parameters-and-nil),

making

```
var minDNode: DNode?
```

into

```
var minDNode: DNode? = nil
```

didn't solve the problem

Comment: Why does `merge()`  take inout parameters? The arguments are not modified, so this seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: oh,, i cut out the long part out from the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MartinR makes a good point in the comments: *"Why does merge() take inout parameters? The arguments are not modified, so this seems like an unnecessary complication."*

The reason for the error is that you have to pass the exact type when using `inout`, and `DNode` and `DNode?` are two different types.
`newNode` needs to be declared as optional because that is what merge is expecting:

```
func start(inout newNode: DNode?) {
    self.minDNode = merge(&self.minDNode, And: &newNode) // this call now works
}
```

You probably should rework your code, though, to remove the `inout` calls where they aren't needed.