# Is there a way to use a Template, and In-Out Parameter and Optional together?

Tags: swift, templates, pass-by-reference, optional-parameters

I ran into some interesting behaviour the other day. Basically I originally wrote a helper function to prevent errors while automatically typecasting a JSON property. It looked like this:

```
func readData<T>(inout output:T, _ input:AnyObject?, _ throwError:Bool = true) throws
{
    if (input == nil) {
        if (throwError) {
            throw ConvertError.MissingParameter
        }
    }
    else {
        if let inputObject:T = input as? T {
            output = inputObject
        }
        else if (throwError) {
            throw ConvertError.WrongType
        }
    }
}

var myProperty:String
try readData(&myProperty, myJson["data"], true)
```

This checks the property exists, and that it's the right type. If all goes well, the value inside **myProperty** changes.

A little while later, I needed to make some changes. I made a class called **properties** and it has a list of properties inside of it. There are 2 variables of this type of class: **originalProperties** and **modifiedProperties** Each of the properties inside these classes are optional variables now, specifically to keep track of what properties the user has changed. Basically it looks like this:

```
class Properties
{
    var x:Int?
    var y:Int?
}
```

Now when I run this:

```
try readData(&originalProperties.x, myJson["x"], false)
```

It doesn't work anymore. I looked at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690710/swift-optional-inout-parameters-and-nil) and it explained what was happening. Basically while **x** still had a value of *nil* (because it's an optional), I was passing a nil value into my *readData* function, so the Template type  isn't set properly and that's why it fails on the *input as? T* code.

fortunately, I don't have to have such a creative function anymore. I can just use this:

```
originalProperties.x= obj["x"] as? Int
```

But then I'll lose my thrown error functionality if I needed it.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can make sure my Template type gets passed correctly while it still has a value of nil? I even read in another thread that I might have to use some sort of default value closure, but it would be interesting to see if there's a way to work around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that the generic `T` can never *itself* know if it is of `Optional` type or not, which makes successful type conversion to `T` tricky for the cases when `T` is in fact of type `Optional<SomeType>`. We could, ourselves, assert that `T` is an optional type (checking `Mirror(reflecting: ...).displayStyle == .Optional` etc), however this still doesn't solve conversion to `T` right off the bat. Instead, we could use another approach, as follows below.

We can work around the problem by creating two `readData(...)` functions, one taking an optional generic `inout` parameter, type `U?`, and the other one taking an implicitly non-optional generic `inout` parameter `U` (called only if `U?` function cannot be used, hence implicitly only called for non-optionals). These two functions, in turn, are minimal and basically only calls your "core" `dataReader(..)` function, where we've made the adjustment that the `inout` generic parameter is now explicitly optional, i.e., `T?`.

```
enum ConvertError: ErrorType {
    case MissingParameter
    case WrongType
}

/* optional inout parameter */
func readData<U>(inout output: U?, _ input: AnyObject?, _ throwError: Bool = true) throws {
    try readDataCore(&output, input, throwError)
}

/* non-optional inout parameter */
func readData<U>(inout output: U, _ input: AnyObject?, _ throwError: Bool = true) throws {
    var outputOpt : U? = output
    try readDataCore(&outputOpt, input, throwError)
    output = outputOpt!
    /* you could use a guard-throw here for the unwrapping of 'outputOpt', but
       note that 'outputOpt' is initialized with a non-nil value, and that it can
       never become 'nil' in readDataHelper; so "safe" forced unwrapping here.    */
}

/* "core" function */
func readDataCore<T>(inout output: T?, _ input: AnyObject?, _ throwError: Bool = true) throws
{
    if (input == nil) {
        if (throwError) {
            throw ConvertError.MissingParameter
        }
    }
    else {
        if let inputObject: T = input as? T {
            output = inputObject
        }
        else if (throwError) {
            throw ConvertError.WrongType
        }
    }
}
```

As we try this out, we see that we now get the behaviour we're looking for, even if the argument sent as `inout` parameter is `nil` or `Optional`.

---

***Example 1***: using optional `inout` param with value `nil`

```
class Properties
{
    var x:Int?
    var y:Int?
}

var myJson : [String:Int] = ["data":10]
var originalProperties = Properties()

do {
    try readData(&originalProperties.x, myJson["data"], true)
    print("originalProperties.x = \(originalProperties.x ?? 0)")
} catch ConvertError.MissingParameter {
    print("Missing parameter")
} catch ConvertError.WrongType {
    print("Wrong type")
} catch {
    print("Unknown error")
}
/* Prints: 'originalProperties.x = 10', ok! */

// try some non-existing key 'foo'
do {
    try readData(&originalProperties.x, myJson["foo"], true)
    print("originalProperties.x = \(originalProperties.x ?? 0)")
} catch ConvertError.MissingParameter {
    print("Missing parameter")
} catch ConvertError.WrongType {
    print("Wrong type")
} catch {
    print("Unknown error")
}
/* Prints: 'Missing parameter', ok! */
```

***Example 2***: using optional `inout` param with, however, with a non-optional value

```
class Properties
{
    var x:Int? = 1
    var y:Int? = 1
}

var myJson : [String:Int] = ["data":10]
var originalProperties = Properties()

// ...

/* Same results as for Example 1: 
   'originalProperties.x = 10' and 'Missing parameter' */
```

***Example 3***: using non-optional `inout` parameter

```
class Properties
{
    var x:Int = 1
    var y:Int = 1
}

var myJson : [String:Int] = ["data":10]
var originalProperties = Properties()

// ...

/* Same results as for Example 1: 
   'originalProperties.x = 10' and 'Missing parameter' */
```

Comment: Nice, it works! I didn't think to use function overloading to solve the problem, but that fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: @GlenHeide Happy to help!