# NULL parameter in Swift

Tags: swift

In Objective-C, we can declare a function like this:

```
- (void)getRect:(CGRect *)aRectRef bRect:(CGRect *)bRectRef
{
    if (aRectRef) *aRectRef = CGRectZero
    if (bRectRef) *bRectRef = CGRectZero
}
```

and pass `NULL` to the function:

```
CGRect rect;
[self getRect:NULL bRect:rect]
```

There isn't `NULL` in Swift. I can't use `nil` as inout param directly either:

```
func getRect(aRect aRectRef: inout CGRect?, bRect bRectRef: inout CGRect?) -> Void {
    ...
}
self.getRect(&nil, bRect: rect) // <- ERROR
```

**I must define a variable with nil value and pass it to the function, even though I don't need the variable totally.**

How to pass `nil` to the function?

UPDATE:

[null / nil in swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043589/null-nil-in-swift-language) just explained `nil` in Swift.

[Swift optional inout parameters and nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690710/swift-optional-inout-parameters-and-nil) explained how to define a variable with nil value and pass it as inout parameter.

I want to know there is a way to pass nil directly like `&nil` to function or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [null / nil in swift language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043589/null-nil-in-swift-language)

Comment: I found it before, it didn't solve my question.

Comment: If you already found it, why didn't you mention it in your question and explain why the answer in question doesn't help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift optional inout parameters and nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690710/swift-optional-inout-parameters-and-nil)

Comment: It is really inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Objective-C method has nullable pointers as parameters, 
in Swift 3 that would be an optional `UnsafeMutablePointer`:

```
func getRect(aRectRef: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>?, bRectRef: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>?) {
    if let aRectPtr = aRectRef {
        aRectPtr.pointee = CGRect(x: 1, y: 2, width: 3, height: 4)
    }
    if let bRectPtr = bRectRef {
        bRectPtr.pointee = CGRect(x: 5, y: 6, width: 7, height: 8)
    }
}

var rect = CGRect.zero
getRect(aRectRef: &rect, bRectRef: nil)
print(rect) // (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
```

So you can pass `nil` as an argument. What you can *not* do
(in contrast to Objective-C) is to pass the address of an *uninitialized* variable, `rect` must be initialized here.

The same can be written more compactly as

```
func getRect(aRectRef: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>?, bRectRef: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>?) {

    aRectRef.map { $0.pointee = CGRect(x: 1, y: 2, width: 3, height: 4) }
    bRectRef.map { $0.pointee = CGRect(x: 5, y: 6, width: 7, height: 8) }
}
```

Comment: `UnsafeMutablePointer` seems a little tricky, though this is best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not allowed to add comment at this time, so I'll write this as an answer.  In SWIFT, you defined the parameter as inout, you have to pass in a variable and not literal nil.  You can do something like this,

```
func testGetRect()
    {
        var recta: CGRect? = nil
        var rectb: CGRect? = CGRect()

        self.getRect(aRect: &recta, bRect: &rectb)
    }

    func getRect(inout aRect aRectRef: CGRect?, inout bRect bRectRef: CGRect?) -> Void
    {
        if (aRectRef != nil)
        {
            aRectRef = CGRectZero
        }
        if (bRectRef != nil)
        {
            bRectRef = CGRectZero
        }

    }
```

Yes, you "must define a variable with nil and pass it to the function.  I tried some casting to see if it work, but couldn't.  The parameter passing with inout is like C++ parameter passing by reference, i.e foo(int &parama, int &paramb).  You must pass a variables to foo.  I don't believe SWIFT has parameter passing like the obj-c example that you have.